# Knockout Validation: Dynamically define Required onlyIf rule

Tags: validation, knockout.js, knockout-validation

How do I define the required "onlyIf" rules dynamically?

I get the rules fo all my inputs from the server, in this format:

```
"Var1" => array("required"=>"onlyIf", "requiredIf"=>"Var2", "min"=>1, "max"=>1000)
```

and I loop through all the rules to setup the rule object for KO validation in this way:

```
for (var key in rules) {
  var rule = new Object();
  if (typeof (key.required) != "undefined") 
    rule.required = key.required == "onlyIf" ? {
      onlyIf: function () {
        return self[self.rules[key].requiredIf]();
      }
  }: key.required;
}
```

That doesn't work, because the `key` variable is only defined in that loop.

I don't want to explicitly define the "onlyIf" rules because I have >100 variables to deal with, and those rules are already present on the server.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up constructing the `onlyIf` object as a string and executed it with `eval()`:

```
for (var key in rules) {
  var rule = new Object();
  if (typeof (key.required) != "undefined") {
    if (key.required == "onlyIf") {
        onlyIf = eval( "onlyIf={onlyIf: function() { return self."+key.requiredIf+"(); }}" );
        thisRule.required= onlyIf;
    } else {
        thisRule.required = key.required;
    }
  }
}
```

This works, as far as I can tell, but it doesn't feel ideal. I will also have to test if it works cross-browser.